# Connecting to a wired network of a remote machine via terminal

Tags: networking, command-line, bash, remote-access, anydesk

I'm connecting to a remote machine in my office via AnyDesk. It is a business network and I have to enter a password after a reboot or a password change. The PC prompts me to enter a password.

I have to change my password due to security regulations of the company and I will lose the connection, is there any way to write a bash script to connect the PC to the internet?

```
ip addr info
```

gave the following output;

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp42s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:bb:c1:3d:d2:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.20.8.187/16 brd 10.20.255.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp42s0
       valid_lft 48830sec preferred_lft 48830sec
    inet6 fe80::b0d2:f718:1740:eed9/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 172.17.0.114 peer 172.17.0.113/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1b:82b3:ee95:5818/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```